# Rails 4 - How to render the same view after submit form

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

How to render the same view after submit form?

I'm unable to render custom partial error messages. I guess its due to I need to render the same view but I don't know how to do that. I tried all the lines commented   because I need to

```
   def create
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])
    @comment = @micropost.comments.create(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id #or whatever is you session name
    if @comment.save
      flash[:success] = "Comment created!"
      redirect_to :back
    else
      @new_comment = @micropost.comments.new
      #flash[:danger] = "Max 140 caracteres - No puede estar en blanco!" #works but is static single comment.
      #render 'microposts/show', locals: {micropost: @micropost} # I need to define all variables to in this controller again and pass to the partial (It's not DRY) 
      #redirect_to micropost_url(@micropost)  # works but not show partial errors messages
    end
  end
```

Routes:

```
  resources :microposts do
    member do
      get :likes
    end
    [:create, :destroy, :show, :index]
    resources :comments
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

As the flash messages are simple name value pair hashes.
I think you should give the flash message in your view or partial like this :-

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
        <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
      <% end %>
```

And in you should define the flash messages in your controllers action. Which you have already done .

Hope it works !

Answer (score 0):

on your **create**

```
def create
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])
    @comment = @micropost.comments.create(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id #or whatever is you session name
    respond_to do |format|
        if @comment.save
            flash[:success] = "Comment created!"
            redirect_to :back
            format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
        else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            #flash[:danger] = "Max 140 caracteres - No puede estar en blanco!" #works but is static single comment.
            #render 'microposts/show', locals: {micropost: @micropost} # I need to define all variables to in this controller again and pass to the partial (It's not DRY) 
            #redirect_to micropost_url(@micropost)  # works but not show partial errors messages
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, what I need to have in 'new' template? with your solution I get: "Missing template comments/new, application/new"

Answer (score 0):

Reading I can see this a duplicated of [custom validations errors form controller inside other parent controller rails 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838227/custom-validations-errors-form-controller-inside-other-parent-controller-rails-3).

However The only solution I see is violating DRY and define all the variables needed by parent view inside Comment#create.

This also cause a to show the post page in another url /post/:id/comment  which is not correct.

Now I see why other suggest to not use nested resources

I cant believe there isn't a simple, out of the box solution for a common problem like this.